# MS SQL: XML translater

Tags: sql-server, xml, exact-synergy-enterprise

I want to extract the `itemnumber` from the XML data to columns.
However in the XML file there is more than 1 value (itemnumber) per row.
 (there could be about 100 itemnumbers per row)

My query works good but its too slow due to the amount of sub-queries I'd have to make to extract all the data out of the XML

The sub-query looks like this

```
SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(table/id/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),37),36)   AS id, 
Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[9]','VARCHAR(255)')   AS 'item', 
Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Batchnummer"]/@value)[9]','VARCHAR(255)') AS Batch, 
Cast(x.data AS XML).value('(//column[@name="Aantal"]/@value)[9]','INT')                AS Aantal 
             FROM   synergy..xmldata x (nolock) 
             WHERE  Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[9]','VARCHAR(255)') IS NOT NULL
```

Now this works good but I have to use `Union all` about 100 times to extract all the data

Is there an easier way to do this?

This is what the full query looks like (FYI I used statement `Union all` 3 times, if I want it to work I have to copy/paste that 100 times and change the value amount */@value)[xxxx]* )

```
SELECT    XMLDATA.id , 
      XMLDATA.item , 
      XMLDATA.batchnummer , 
      XMLDATA.aantal , 
      y.freetextfield_02 
FROM     ( 
             SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(table/id/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),37),36)   AS id, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(255)')   AS 'item', 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Batchnummer"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(255)') AS Batch, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value('(//column[@name="Aantal"]/@value)[1]','INT')                AS Aantal
             FROM   synergy..xmldata x (nolock) 
             WHERE  Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(255)') IS NOT NULL 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(table/id/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),37),36)   AS id, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[2]','VARCHAR(255)')   AS 'item', 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Batchnummer"]/@value)[2]','VARCHAR(255)') AS Batch, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value('(//column[@name="Aantal"]/@value)[2]','INT')                AS Aantal
             FROM   synergy..xmldata x (nolock) 
             WHERE  Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[2]','VARCHAR(255)') IS NOT NULL 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT RIGHT(LEFT(Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(table/id/text())[1]','varchar(100)'),37),36)   AS id, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[3]','VARCHAR(255)')   AS 'item', 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Batchnummer"]/@value)[3]','VARCHAR(255)') AS Batch, 
                    Cast(x.data AS XML).value('(//column[@name="Aantal"]/@value)[3]','INT')                AS Aantal 
             FROM   synergy..xmldata x (nolock) 
             WHERE  Cast(x.data AS XML).value ('(//column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[3]','VARCHAR(255)') IS NOT NULL 
                ) XMLDATA 
LEFT JOIN synergy..absences y (nolock) 
ON        y.id = XMLDATA.id 
WHERE     y. freetextfield_02 IS NOT NULL 
AND       type IN ('126', 
               '129')
```

this is what the XML looks like:

```
<table>
<id>{351CE2EE-59E8-43B0-B95B-81A24A2C037E}</id>
<rows>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="4" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="5" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="3.46331132.NL" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="190259" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="10" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="14" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
  </row>
  </rows>
  <key>DefaultKey</key>
  <total>0</total>
  <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
  <data />
  <parameters />
  </table>
```

This is what the dataset `TABLE`  looks like i'm extracting the xml from the column `Data` 
[DATASET XML IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9qjH.png)

Comment: did you consider to do it in some of the programming languages designed for that (c# for example)

Comment: yes, however we are using mssql for this. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `nodes` to create a row in the dataset for each `columns` node. Then you can treat it like a data set:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '<table>
<id>{351CE2EE-59E8-43B0-B95B-81A24A2C037E}</id>
<rows>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="2" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="3" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="4" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="101445.A.FF" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="PR1900002366" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="1" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="5" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
</row>
<row>
  <columns>
    <column name="Artikelen" value="3.46331132.NL" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Batchnummer" value="190259" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Aantal" value="10" type="System.Int32" />
    <column name="Opmerkingen" value="retour" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Magazijn" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="Reden" value="" type="System.String" />
    <column name="DefaultKey" value="14" type="System.Int32" />
  </columns>
  </row>
  </rows>
  <key>DefaultKey</key>
  <total>0</total>
  <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
  <data />
  <parameters />
  </table>';

SELECT V.X.value('(/table/id/text())[1]','varchar(255)') AS id,
       r.c.value('(./column[@name="Artikelen"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS item,
       r.c.value('(./column[@name="Batchnummer"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Batch,
       r.c.value('(./column[@name="Aantal"]/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Aantal
FROM (VALUES (@XML)) V (X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('table/rows/row/columns') r(c);
```

Comment: I wasn't, @josefermin . The comment was deleted after I made the comment, but Id din't realise until after you messaged me asking why I told you told. Yes, it's not relevant now, but it was... I've only engaged further as you asked why I told you that. I have deleted all the comments now.

Comment: More on topic, if this worked, then please consider marking it as the answer so that future readers know it was helpful, @josefermin .